# Problema con jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

No puedo hacer funcionar jQuery
Esta es mi web [bersekerprueba.esy.es](http://bersekerprueba.esy.es)

Lo descargue y segui estas instrucciones 
http://basic-slider.com/

¿Qué me falta?

***En mi FTP tengo las carpetas***

bjqs.css

demo.css

Estilos.css

Index.html

**Carpeta /** Imagenes ( Con las 3 imagenes llamadas 1 2 y 3)

**Carpeta /** Js (jquery-3.0.0.min ////
    bjqs-1.3.min.js ////
    bjqs-1.3.js)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head> 
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <meta name="Indumentaria Zona Oeste" content="Indumentaria"/>
 <meta name="berseker, berserkerbsas, brsker" content="Berseker, Indumentaria">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.bxslider.css">
 <link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the plugin *after* the jQuery library -->
<script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the basic styles -->
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="bjqs.css" />

</head>


<h1 align= center>
  <img src= Imagenes\header.jpg>
</h1>
 </div>
 <span class="fuente-1"> 
 <div class="inner">

<nav> 
 <ul>
  <li><a href=”A”>Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href=”A”>Modelos</a></li>
  <li><a href=”A”>Social</a></li>
  <li><a href="A">Contacto</a></li>
 </ul>  
 </div>
</nav>

<body>
<div id="my-slideshow">
 <ul class="bjqs">
  <img src="Imagenes/1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
  <img src="Imagenes/2.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script class="secret-source">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

          $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
            height      : 320,
            width       : 620,
            responsive  : true
          });

        });
 </script>
 <script src="js/libs/jquery.secret-source.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {

        $('.secret-source').secretSource({
            includeTag: false
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿por qué utilizas dos versiones distintas de jQuery? 1.11.1 y 3.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al ver los logs de la consola estas llamando mal las librerias y el css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.bxslider.css">
<link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="bjqs.css" />
```

Debería ser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path_completo/jquery.bxslider.css">
<link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="path_completo/bjqs.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="path_completo/bjqs.css" />
```

Donde path_completo es la ruta donde se encuentra esos archivos, por ejemplo podría ser:

```
<script src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
```

**EDIT**

Una vez que ya tienes bien las llamadas a cada archivo, estuve revisando el código html y tienes etiquetas sin abrir, por ejemplo dentro del **`<ul>`** donde colocas las imágenes te falta poner las etiquetas **`<li>`** para cada imagen, revisa esos errores, y prueba de nuevo.

También en $('#banner-fade') estas colocando el id incorrecto, debería ser: $('#my-slideshow') ya que ese id le estas dando al div que contiene el slide.

Comment: @Nahuel puse un edit en base a la respuesta que diste.

Comment: Hola juan, antes que nada gracias por ayudarme. Ya cerre las etiquetas y sigue sin funcionar. <body>
<div id="my-slideshow">
 <ul class="bjqs">
  <li><img src="Imagenes/1.jpg" title="Caption"></li>
  <li><img src="Imagenes/2.jpg" title="Caption"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

Comment: @NahuelPalacios en $('#banner-fade') estas colocando el id incorrecto, deberia ser: $('#my-slideshow') ya que ese id le estas dando al div que contiene el slide. Ese <span class="fuente-1"> para que lo usas??

Comment: Ya funciono, gracias!

Comment: @NahuelPalacios Si la respuesta te fue útil, marcala como solución, así otros usuarios pueden encontrarla útil.

Answer (score 0):

En tu página web arroja un error como si no existiera el archivo **js/bjqs.min.js**:

1.- Yo creo que no has cargado los archivos **js/bjqs.min.js**

2-.bien los permisos de lectura no están configurados correctamente

---

**EDICIÓN POR NUEVA RESPUESTA**

Tal como me lo temia, no existe ningun archivo llamado: **js/bjqs.min.js**.

Tu archivo se llama: **js/bjqs-1.3.min.js**